# Modify the default website in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis

I have IIS installed on a server.

It is currently on the intranet as http://mySite which has a few basic html pages that load when you go to that URL

I've made a virtual directory called MyWebApp, which sits at http://mySite/MyWebApp

How do I go about making MyWebApp the default site when you type mySite into the browser?

I don't want it to come up as mySite/MyWebApp when you visit the page either.. I just want it to always say mySite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be simpler to build your app in your root directory?  However, you can change the root directory of your IIS6 website by:

To change the home directory of a Web site using IIS Manager

1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, expand the Web Sites directory, right-click the Web site you wish to change, and click Stop.
2. Use Windows Explorer, to rename the LocalDrive:\Inetpub\Wwwroot directory to the name of your choice. Alternatively, you can copy the entire \Wwwroot directory tree to a new location.